# Bat file to Change folder names

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with a bunch of subfolders. How would I wirte a bat file to append 8 random characters to the end of the folder names.

The first step I went through was placing files into the subfolders below, with this code:

```
for %%i in (PathToWorkingFolder\*) do mkdir "PathToWorkingFolder\%%~ni" & move "%%i" "PathToWorkingFolder\%%~ni"
```

The folder names are :

FD3_2012-10_Stmt

FD3_2012-10_Tax

FD3_2012-10_Warr

Comment: Why move files if all you want is renaming folders (by appending characters)?

Comment: There is actually a 2 step process. The first step is move the files in a folder called "reports" into subfolers, and then add 8 random number characters at the end of the folder name.

Comment: @JerryTrac: Try to accept a larger amount of best answers, otherwise the people will lost interest in answer your questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two steps may be achieved in the same FOR:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (PathToWorkingFolder\*) do (
   rem Get folder name with 8 random digits at end
   digits=000000!random!!random!
   set "folder=%%~Ni!digits:~-8!"
   rem Create the subfolder and move the file
   mkdir "PathToWorkingFolder\!folder!"
   move "%%i" "PathToWorkingFolder\!folder!"
)
```